# Nested Master Page Issues

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I've read about 13 different pages to try to figure out why my NestedMasterPage doesn't work, 3 of which were on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to be working.

My NestedMasterPage looks like this(the way it originally looked when it was generated):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PTNestedMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MyNS.NestedMasterPages.PTNestedMasterPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

My Site.Master is pretty big, but its asp:ContentPlaceHolder's look like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MyNS.SiteMaster" %>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
```

I'm trying to add content to a new page but that's when i get the error:

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a
>   nested master page that references a master page.

My page looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/NestedMasterPages/PTNestedMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="M1Gloss.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNS.PTFrame.Module_1" %>


<asp:Content ID="fContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content3" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks Malik

Comment: what you try to do in the last code snippet is to append a `asp:Content` element into another `asp:Content` element. Not like in the second snippet into a `asp:ContentPlaceHolder`

Comment: Your nested master page seems to be lacking `ConentPlaceHolder`s

Comment: that's how it was generated. where/how would I place them?

Comment: Pardon me for asking but why do you need nested master pages? On every occasion I have come across them they weren't needed and could have been obviated by a better understanding of CSS.

Comment: @IrishChieftain I just wanted to use the master page layout and VS told me that I needed a nested one, so I made it.

Comment: Depending on how much work you have already invested, I would start again with only a single master page and keep it simple :-)

Comment: When I tried referencing my Master page in my Forms, VS told me I needed to create a nested one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, 
My NestedMasterPage is supposed to look like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PTNestedMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MyNS.NestedMasterPages.PTNestedMasterPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```